# Insertar varios registros desde un solo formulario usando TypeScript de Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, aplicación-web

**Necesito ayuda para realizar un insert múltiple desde un mismo formulario
es decir tengo que enviar a mi base de datos respuesta a 2 preguntas diferentes
1.-respuesta 1
2.-respuesta 2
este es mi formulario:**

```html
<form  method="post" class="row g-3">

<div *ngFor="let item of preguntas ">

  <input type="text"  name="DescripcionRespuesta[]" id="descripcion1" [(ngModel)]="respuesta.descripcionRespuesta1">
  
    <input type="text"  name="DescripcionRespuesta[]" id="descripcion2" [(ngModel)]="respuesta.descripcionRespuesta2">

<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddSolicitud(respuesta)" style="margin-bottom: 12px; margin-top: 12px;"
    type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </div>

  </form>
```

**y este es el método que utilizo para enviar la información a mi base de datos:**

```js
 onAddRespuestas(respuestas:Respuestas): void {
    this._respuestaService.addRespuestas(respuesta).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res) {
      console.log('Exito')
      } else {
        alert('Error! :('Error al guardar la información')

      }
    })
  }
```

**El detalle es que no puedo realizar mas de un insert a la base de datos.**

Comment: El método  onAddRespuestas()  solo puede enviar una pregunta con su respuesta a la vez ?

Comment: hola, exacto. se crea la pregunta con su respuesta, pero no importa cantos inputs coloque, solo toma el primero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo haces un ngFor de un array llamado "preguntas" del cual también haces el binding con los inputs generados, en este caso puedes recorrer el array con un  foreach y ejecutar la función onAddRespuestas() por cada pregunta.

Un ejemplo sencillo.

```
preguntas.forEach((pregunta) => onAddRespuestas(pregunta));
```

Comment: listo, me funciono,  puedo realizar la inserción agregue un nuevo método y adapte a la respuesta que me enviaste. onAddSolicitud(respuesta:Respuesta): void {
   
    this._preguntaService.addRespuestaET(respuesta).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res) {
      console.log('Exito')
      } else {
        alert('Error! :(')

      }
    })


  }

  agregar(respuesta:Respuesta){
    this.datos.forEach(() => this.onAddSolicitud(respuesta));
  }

Comment: hace falta trabajarlo un poco para ya esta la solución. muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro!! que tengas suerte